# ng-table filterData does not work

Tags: angularjs-ng-table

Please help to point the problem in my code bellow: why the drop down select items are not shown. I went through the [ngTable Example](http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-select) it did not give me all the details. I cannot find the source `ngTableDemos` so I have no idea what the `filterData` should exactly be and it is made by my guess.

```js
      "use strict";
      angular.module('myApp', ['ngTable']).controller("myCtrl", ['NgTableParams', function (NgTableParams) {
        this.cols = [
          {field: 'name', title: 'Name', filter: {name: 'text'}},
          {field: 'age', title: 'Age', filter: {age: 'number'}},
          {field: 'gender', title: 'Gender', filter: {gender: 'select'}, filterData: ['male', 'female', 'shemale']}
        ];
        this.tbParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
          dataset: [
            {name:'abc1001',age:11,gender:'male'},
            {name:'abc1002',age:12,gender:'female'},
            {name:'abc1003',age:13,gender:'shemale'}
          ]
        });
      }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head lang="en">
    <title>demo23</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@4.0.0/bundles/ng-table.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@4.0.0/bundles/ng-table.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller = "myCtrl as ctrl">
      <table ng-table-dynamic="ctrl.tbParams with ctrl.cols" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
          <td ng-repeat="col in $columns" >{{row[col.field]}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I dig into the *ng-table.js* (4.0.0) and found the answer. Line 2841:

```
var html = "<select ng-options=\"data.id as data.title for data in $column.data\"\n        ng-disabled=\"$filterRow.disabled\"\n        multiple ng-multiple=\"true\"\n        ng-model=\"params.filter()[name]\"\n        class=\"filter filter-select-multiple form-control\" name=\"{{name}}\">\n</select>\n";
```

So I changed my code: `filterData: ['male', 'female', 'shemale']` to `filterData: [{id: 'male', title: 'male'}, {id: 'female', title: 'female'}, {id: 'shemale', title: 'shemale'}]`; then it worked. Of course, `filterData: [{id: 'male', title: 'Male'}, {id: 'female', title: 'Female'}, {id: 'shemale', title: 'She-Male'}]` also worked.

Comparing to smart-table, I fell that ng-table is more sophisticated. But reading the document to make my own code is a real challenge. Appreciate if they may provide codes on dependencies and move from codepen to plunker.